# Как Векторизовать большие текстовые данные в pyspark

Tags: nlp, pyspark, word2vec

Необходимо векторизовать полученные спарсенные данные. Препроцессинг пройден, тип данных ArrayString. Данных 9 тыс.строк. Если попробовать код на 10 строках,  то все отрабатывает отлично, если на всем датафрейме, то процесс сильно грузится.
Работаю в Jupyter Notebook.

Pyspark.

[image: SparkSession]

Данные:

[image: Данные]

Код:

```
word2Vec = Word2Vec(vectorSize=3, minCount = 0, inputCol = 'finished', outputCol =  'result')
```

`model = word2Vec.fit(df2)`

```
result = model.transform(df2)
```